# Styling D3 graphic in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, d3.js

I am trying to render the following D3 graph in a rails view:

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4063570

It shows up OK, except it's completely black and the lines don't show up well either (screenshot permalink):
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s116/sh/5d2b40c6-2bd0-49a7-8ead-c29713cc5ed7/2ca5e19814e84f05d5709232b3edec6f/deep/0/Screenshot%207/5/13%207:07%20PM.png

Here's the code in my view (I was having trouble getting it to render at all when the js was in the assets pipeline):

/app/views/steps/mindmap.html.erb

```
    <%= javascript_tag do %>
        var width = 960,
        height = 2200;

        var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
        .size([height, width - 160]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

        d3.json("/assets/flare.json", function(root) {
        var nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
        links = cluster.links(nodes);

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

        node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5);

        node.append("text")
        .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
        .attr("dy", 3)
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
        });

        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
    <% end %>
```

and app/assets/mindmap.css:

```
    .node circle {
      fill: #7A8B8B;
      stroke: #7A8B8B;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: #7A8B8B;
      stroke: #7A8B8B;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

I've tried changing the color and other attributes to no effect. The CSS settings don't seem to have any impact on the way D3 renders the graphic. Is this a Rails/asset pipeline problem, a javascript problem, or perhaps something special about how D3 renders SVGs?

Thanks for any insights you may have!

Comment: If your js was failing with the assets pipeline then it's likely that your CSS is failing too. To verify this, put the contents of mindmap.css into your main app css and it will probably render fine.

Comment: Wow - that worked! Good call! If you add your response below I'll select it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JavaScript was failing with the assets pipeline then it's likely that your CSS is failing too. To verify this, put the contents of `mindmap.css` into your main app css and it wil render fine.

The reason why the assets pipeline is not including your files might be due to configuration or some other reason unrelated to your code.